# Arrow keys on filtered combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, combobox

I have a simple combo box which has a datatable using .DefaultView as items source. I placed a filter on the combo box with the following code:

```
    private void FilterCombobox(ComboBox cmb, string columnName)
    {
        DataView view = (DataView)cmb.ItemsSource;
        view.RowFilter = (columnName + " like '*" + cmb.Text + "*'");

        cmb.ItemsSource = view;
        cmb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }
```

The XAML for the combo box is:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbRigNum" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="470,440,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="206" SelectionChanged="cmbRigNum_SelectionChanged" IsEditable="True" StaysOpenOnEdit="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" KeyUp="cmbRigNum_KeyUp"/>
```

Update: The Key_Up event:

```
    private void cmbRigNum_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        FilterCombobox(cmbRigNum, "RigNumber");         
    }
```

Everything works wonderfully when the user types, but as soon as the arrow keys are used to make selection the filtered list disappears and the value in the combo box is cleared. How do I enable a user to navigate with arrow keys through the filtered list that is displayed when the user initially types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with the suggestion @Topher Birth gave, I found a solution to the problem. For anyone struggling with the same issue here is the code that resolved the problem:

```
     private void FilterCombobox(ComboBox cmb, string columnName)
    {
        //because the itemsSource of the comboboxes are datatables, filtering is not supported. Converting the itemsSource to a
        //dataview will allow the functionality of filtering to be implemented
        DataView view = (DataView)cmb.ItemsSource;
        view.RowFilter = (columnName + " like '*" + cmb.Text + "*'");

        cmb.ItemsSource = view;
        cmb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }

    private void cmbRigNum_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.Down & e.Key != Key.Up) 
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            FilterCombobox(cmbRigNum, "RigNumber");
        }
    }
```

Can't believe it was actually so simple. Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that it is something in your "cmbRigNum_KeyUp" method.

edit:
So if you don't want it changing the filter with the arrow keys, could you do something like this?

```
private void cmbRigNum_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(e.Keychar) || char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) // Add more characters as needed.
    {
        FilterCombobox(cmbRigNum, "RigNumber");
    {
}
```

Comment: @BabyDoll ... see edit. If you want all but arrow keys then you could look for them not being the Keychar.

Comment: I simply need the user to make a selection (navigate throught the items) using the arrows. Currently when the filter list appears and the down arrow (for example) is pressed nothing happends. So it does not change the filter when I press the arrow, but it doesn't start navigation either

Comment: There is no KeyChar property in WPF but I implemented something similar using e.Key. But still no luck. It's like when the arrow is pressed it does not register that it needs to select an item/index